# Where is documented that no other transaction can update a locked row?

Tags: mysql-5.7

In the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html) for InnoDB Locking, it is stated how shared and exclusive locks work.

As I found out by trial and error, both `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` and `FOR UPDATE` ensure no other transaction can update the rows that are selected.

What I found in the documentation, is that if a row is locked `FOR UPDATE` then no other transaction can get a LOCK until the transaction is commited or rolled back. Also if there are multiple `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` then no updated are possible. But I did not find that if there is any LOCK on a row, than no transaction (even without LOCK) can update the row.

I did not find that rule in the docs. Is it missing, or did I just overread it?

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> if there is any LOCK on a row, [then] no transaction (even without LOCK) can update the row

On the page you have linked to you can read that

> An exclusive (X) lock permits the transaction that holds the lock to update or delete a row

which means that *before* a transaction can update a row it *must* acquire an X lock on it, which is impossible<sup>1</sup> if there is already an S or X lock on that row placed by a [locking read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) in another transaction.

---

1 -- because X, which as we know stands for "exclusive",  is incompatible with any other lock.